# CSS3 Transition Bug in Chrome creates weird background colors

Tags: google-chrome, css, background-color, transition

I'm trying to make smooth animations on buttons by implementing CSS3's transition properties.  The buttons smoothly go from dark green to light green in **Firefox**, **Safari**, and **Opera** (IE doesn't support transitions anyways).

But for some reason, in **Chrome**, if you hover over one button and then immediately hover over another, the colors seem to lag.  Sometimes I get a neon green button, sometimes I get a black button; something happens whenever I run the mouse too fast from one button to the next.  Can Chrome just not keep up with the transitions or something?

Barebones code I'm using:

```
.button {  
transition: background-color 0.2s;  
-moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;  
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;  
background-color: #466b46; 
}

.button:hover {  
background-color: #74d06c;  
}
```

Chrome is Version 24.0.1312.56.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: off-topic, but i ended up here. also in chrome -- i was getting weird bars of solid colors when trying to transition a backdrop with a solid rgba background color.  switching to opacity fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

if I clearly understand your problem you want a smooth transition in chrome when you hover a button ? 
For that change your code like this :

```
.button {  
     transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     -moz-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     background-color: #466b46; 
}

.button:hover {  
     transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     -moz-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     -webkit-transition: background-color linear 0.2s;  
     background-color: #74d06c;  
}
```

with this code, if you change the hover over a button, you have also a smooth transition to back to the initials parameters.

I hope that this will help you.